# Tile package in Tkinter Python 2.6

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I'm trying to change the look of my Tkinter application but not having much luck. I discovered the tile package and looked around the sites that I've found but nothing I try works. The code for importing that I've used is the following:

```
import Tkinter as Tk
import ttk
import Tile

win1 = Tk()
win1.call('namespace', 'import', '-force', 'ttk::*')
win1.call('tile::setTheme', 'xpnative')
```

Error: _tkinter.TclError : invalid command name 'tile::setTheme'

I'm really stuck on how to get this working for any type of design change to Tkinter. I want my interface to look nice!

Would appreciate any help given, thank you!

Comment: Do you have the option to upgrade to python 2.7? It's built-in to 2.7.

Comment: I don't I'm afraid. I'm restricted to what I have on this machine.

Comment: Tile is just the old name for ttk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tile is just an old version of the ttk package. You don't need it if you already have access to ttk.

For information on how to configure styles, see the [tkdocs tutorial on styles](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/styles.html)

Answer (score 0):

Even though it's not linked to the Tile package. I have found how to obtain the 'xpnative' theme.

Simply:

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk

s = ttk.Style()
s.theme_use('xpnative')
```

Then you may have to insert ttk.[widgethere] for various widgets but it appears to work nevertheless.

Have fun! (Python Version 2.6)